# Remote desktop rearranges icons, but not so they would fit better in small resolutions

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

Logging into my job computer using remote desktop will make the icons rearrange, but not always. Sometimes they do not rearrange.

When I am connected with remote desktop, the icons in the right edge is a waste. When I come back to the computer physically, the icons could or would not be rearranged.

When they are rearranged, they do not necessarily go to a place further to the left. They could move down two places.

Is there anyone that knows the idea behind this?

How do I prevent this if I do not want to install a 3rd party software that would take a snapshot of the icons and later on restore them?

I consider creating two bat files, one that restricts the access to the registry key where icon positions are stored and one that releases the restriction.

However, ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

This typically occurs if you connect to the same server from two different computers that have different resolutions.  For example, a desktop that has 1920x1080 and a notebook that has 1280x1024.

This GPO setting should prevent the desktop shortcuts from being re-arranged:

Policy location: User Configuration > Policies > Administrative Templates > Desktop
Setting: Don't save settings on exit

```
Registry Key:  HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer  
Registry Value: NoSaveSettings
```

Comment: So I have to change that value when I actually want to set icon locations?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Can I have a policy for terminal server sessions and one for local sessions?

Comment: Yes, actually the USER policy linked to the terminal servers OU would only apply to terminal server sessions.  It would not affect local/desktop sessions.

Comment: Oh, there is a problem, I am running windows 7 and I do not use "terminal server", but "remote desktop"... I did not know about the difference

Comment: I am sorry about that, the question is edited now.

Comment: The setting should be the same, although if you are logging on to the same machine both locally and through a remote session, the same policy WOULD apply to both.

Comment: So I cannot have a setting that is automatically applied to remote desktop sessions then.

Comment: Not if you don't want be able to re-arrange your icons in a local session, no.  Sorry!

Comment: If you have permission to modify the registry key, you could create a script that sets the permission to deny Changes when logged on in a remote session, and allow changes if local.  But that is getting a bit klunky.  You may want to migrate this over to SuperUser.